# Insert Wordpress YouTube autoembed in a div

Tags: wordpress, youtube, embed

As you will know when we put a youtube video URL in Wordpress it automagically embeds it and creates a paragraph around it.

If I put:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w8EEhvS0sMU

I will get

```
<p>
<iframe width="474" height="356" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/w8EEhvS0sMU?feature=oembed">
</p>
```

What I'd like to know is how to change this from p to div, so I can move it to the right and have text wrapped in the left of the video.

Does someone know how to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: is it in post content ???

Comment: Yes, is the regular oEmbed code.

Comment: Go to your edit post, use text editor in `text` mode and add `<div>` tag in your content...Hope its work...

Answer (score 0):

You could just take the embed code from the YouTube site, instead of just the video URL, then paste it into your own `<div>` tags and style it however you like.